# Calling web service asynchronously without waiting for response

Tags: android, web-services, asynchronous

I have a situation where, I have 2 buttons.
On each button click, I am calling a web service, which returns me some message (say, it returns "Button 1 clicked" on Button 1 click, and "Button 2 clicked" on Button 2 click).

In my web method, I have defined a delay of 3 seconds for the response to be sent for Button 2.

Now, when I click Button 1, I instantly get the return message ("Button 1 clicked") and then when I click Button 2, i get the return message ("Button 2 clicked") 3 seconds late, which is fine.

If I click Button 2 and then click Button 1, then until and unless the response message for Button 2 does not come (i.e., after 3 seconds), Button 1 response message is also delayed.

I want to remove this delay, i.e., as soon as Button 1 gets clicked, its response message should be arrived.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

This is my inner class :

```
private class UseDataForCommunication extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String receivedContent = "";
    String error = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Send data
        try {

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL(params[0]+params[1]);


            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + " ");
            }

            // Append Server Response To Content String
            receivedContent = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            error = ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        /*****************************************************/
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(receivedContent);
            String parsedResponse = jsonObject.optString("respone");
            receivedMessageViaDataConnection(parsedResponse);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and this is my call from each button's click:

```
new UseDataForCommunication().execute(AppConstants.TRANSMIT_URL,message);
```

Comment: Use the `AsyncTask#executeOnExecutor()` method with the `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` to allow the AsyncTasks to run in parallel. [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) explain it rather well.

Comment: do you want to call webservice on clicking both button

Comment: @Android Yes, the call to web service is made on click of each button.

Comment: same webService or different webservice???

Comment: on clicking button A you will call webservice and clicking B again you want to call same class but with different webservice???? is it right??? @Ali_Waris

Comment: @Android No, both button clicks will call the same web service, but will get  different response as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute multiple AsyncTask by using executeOnExecutor

```
 if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
    new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

For more[check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)